# Bundling NPM module for OFFLINE distribution (with all dependencies)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

How can I create a tarball package for distribution (with all its dependencies)?

The package needs to contain the actual module + all its dependencies since it will be installed locally/offline due to internet restrictions on the organization.

I tried adding the `dependencies` to `bundledDependencies` in package.json then running `npm pack`. But the generated tarball does not include any dependencies I have listed.

I also tried using a module called `npm-pack-all` but it does not work as I intended.

Any way I can do this? Preferably without the need for additional npm modules.

Help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`npm pack` with `bundledDependencies` worked well for me:

[image: tarball]

I am using node v10.15.0 and npm v6.4.1
It even bundled the dependencies that my dependencies need/have.